# Php code to delete all records...should it be working

Tags: php

Should this delete all records in my SQL table?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","bikemap","pedalhard");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("test", $con);

mysql_query("DELETE * FROM gpsdata");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: Does it delete all the records, or does it not work?

Comment: actually I just needed to delete the asterisk from between DELETE and FROM as suggested below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`DELETE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html) doesn't allow a star between `DELETE` and `FROM`. Try this instead:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM gpsdata");
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out MySQL's [Truncate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) command. That should remove all records easily.

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE` differs from `Truncate`. But if your use case is simple, go to any one.

`Truncate`

- DDL command
- You can't rollback
- Table Structure will be re-created.
- Your indexes will be lost.
- Will delete all rows.

`DELETE`

- DML command
- You can rollback.
- Structure remains as it is.
- You can specify a range of rows to delete.